# Inserting a datetime type value into SQL database

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

Currently using pyodbc python module to get some data into a SQL database.

One of the data fields is datetime, and currently the corresponding python variable (which I am trying to load into the SQL database) is formatted like this:

MM/DD/YY HH:MM:SS ##:##

(where the ##:## is an offset to the OS's timezone). Anyways, I am getting the following error:

"The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime date type resulted in an out-of-range value"

I am wondering what my best option is to rectify this. Should I manually edit the python string so that it is in a different format (like YYYY-MM-DD for instance), or is there a SQL conversion function I can use within the INSERT INTO statement? Ultimately, I guess I'm wondering what specifically SQL looks for to convert to datetime so I can adjust my data accordingly.

Thanks!

Comment: Please show *how* you are inserting datetime value in *which* database that supports the industry language, SQL. Also, you are indicating *data fields*. Are you using `pandas` (a separate module that is fundamentally different from general purpose Python)? Please post data and code so we can help.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there are SQL conversion functions like `select convert(varchar, getdate(), 23)` for YYY-MM-DD

```
select convert(varchar, getdate(), 22)
```

for MM/DD/YY HH:MM:SS

yes you can use it for INSERT INTO statement like

```
DECLARE @Tdatetime VARCHAR(MAX) 
SET @Tdatetime = CONVERT( VARCHAR, GETDATE() , 106)
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, ...)
VALUES (@Tdatetime , value2, ...)
```